# Binary operation with two queries in Grafana not working

Tags: grafana

I'm using Infinity datasource plugin for showing stat values. I have two queries, both of them have similar json response, but values are different. In my case I'm getting root values like that: $.total.
[image]
Here's the result:
[image]

I want to get sum of those queries results and hide these values behind the sum, so I added transform "Add field from calculation", binary operation.

[image]
But nothing happen, values on dashboard does not change. The only way sum is working - when I choose same field left and right of plus sign - it sums "wrong assignee + wrong assignee" or "total issues + total issues" correct. If I change one of them to get real sum between different values - nothing. Maybe I'm doing something wrong?

Answer (score 0):

add Filter by name [image]
and select required (new) field name 'Sum' to display